# Search and Replace text, like Notepad

Tags: c#, replace

I have tried to make a search and replace function, in my own version of Notepad. It works, but it only searches and replaces in the first line. How to search and replace, in the whole Notepad (txtNotepad), so the replacement procedure will be more effective?

My code so far:

```
private void metroButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int locaction;
    string myString, search, replace;

    myString  = txtNotepad.Text;
    search    = txtSearchFor.Text.Trim();
    replace   = txtReplaceWith.Text.Trim();
    locaction = txtNotepad.Text.IndexOf(search);

    if (locaction == -1)
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "String not found", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        txtNotepad.Text = myString.Remove(locaction, search.Length).Insert(locaction, replace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use the `.Replace()` function? Your code needs more than simple formatting...

Comment: I would encourage to look into already existing framework [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) before trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't use simply the [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) `Replace` of `string`

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

```
txtNotepad.Text = myString.Replace(search, replace);
```

Comment: Arh, very nice, and simple! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, in 2 minutes, i can! :)

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Done :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Strings Replace-Method in c#.

For example:

```
txtNotepad.Text = myString.Replace(search,replace);
```

Which will replace all occurences of "**search**" with "**replace**".